# How can i check if a background is already set?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Boolean set = false;
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.background1:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redpinkgradientbackground);
            set = true;
            if (set){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.background2:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redgradientbackground);
            set = true;
            if (set){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.background3:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greengradientbackground);
            return true;
        case R.id.background4:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackgreygradientbackground);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to let the user know when a background is set, so when someone picks a background it shows a toast with the text it's 'already set as the background', and when another background is selected is shows the text 'Background set', but when i try it with a boolean which is set to true inside the case statement but it just shows 2  toast when i try it in my app.

Comment: please add tags for the language and the framework. And remove `menuitem` tag which has nothing to do with your post. Please pay attention to the tags you chose for your questions.

Comment: "it doesn't work" it's the worst diagnostics you could give. It tells absolutely nothing about the nature of the issue you are having. Please add the expected result and the result you get.

Comment: add the language tag: e.g. java, javascript, python etc. framework: the framework you use for GUI, e.g. awt, swing, etc. Add the platform if it's relevant, e.g. androind

Comment: when you post a question put yourself in our shoes: can someone who has absolutely no idea what you do and what you are working on understand your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, im new to this forum, i will pay attention to it next time.

Comment: `android-studio` is the IDE you are developing on. Use it only if you are having problems with this particular IDE. I have changed it to `android`

Comment: So do you know how i can solve this problem?

Comment: no, it's been a while since I did a little android. However I did spot something that doesn't make sense: in the 1st case you have `set = true` and then immediately `if (set) .. else` think about it: the `if` condition will always be `true`. The `if` makes no sense. Or the `set = true` above it.

Comment: also: "it shows 2 toast" I don't understand that

Comment: In my app, when i click on a background,  i want to show the user that the background is set or already has been set as the background(toast = text i want to show) , but it show both texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that

```
private int selectedBackgroundId = -1;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.background1:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redpinkgradientbackground);
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.background1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.background1;
            return true;
        case R.id.background2:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redgradientbackground);
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.background2){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.background2;
            return true;
        case R.id.background3:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greengradientbackground);
                if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.background3){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.background3;
            return true;
        case R.id.background4:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackgreygradientbackground);
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.background4){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.background4;
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Not very elegant, but will do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't work, toast only show "Background set" , but not when that particular background is already set as background.

Comment: Make sure to add the if condition and setting selectedBackgroundId  for all your cases, I didn't add it because your original code didn't either, I assumed you are only interested in the first two for some reason

Comment: And in each case also selectedBackgroundId = R.id.background1; ?

Comment: It only show "Background already set" when i change a background and then go back to the first one.

Comment: Ok it works, i had selectedBackgroundId = R.id.background1; in all cases, but the problem now is when i start the app and select the background that already is set, it still show "background set" but when i click again then it shows "Already set".

Comment: private int selectedBackgroundId = -1; this line, change -1 to your default background when you open the app instead.